# Exception: Unable to generate build files in flutter

Tags: android, visual-studio, flutter, kali-linux

I am trying to install flutter in kali linux machine. I installed flutter from official website and followed accordingly. I don't want to use android studio so I am using visual studio code.
when I run Flutter doctor in terminal i get

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 2.2.0-11.0.pre.161, on Linux, locale en_IN)
[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
      `flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.

[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at google-chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[☠] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop (the doctor check crashed)
    ✗ Due to an error, the doctor check did not complete. If the error message below is not helpful, please let us know about this issue at
      https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.
    ✗ ProcessException: Failed to find "ninja" in the search path.
        Command: ninja 
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.55.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 4 categories.
```

And when i Run in visual studio i get this

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Linux in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
Exception: Unable to generate build files
Exited (sigterm)
```

Can anyone help me with this issue please.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the solution by using this following command:

```
sudo apt-get install clang cmake ninja-build pkg-config libgtk-3-dev
```

and

```
flutter config --enable-linux-desktop
```

Comment: Add this command `sudo apt install liblzma-dev` plus yours worked for me

Comment: this worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you must install ninja.

`sudo pacman -S ninja` or `sudo apt-get install ninja`.